# Hadoop: What will be the major difference in writing Map reduce program in hadoop 2.0.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What will be the major changes in writing a map reduce program in Hadoop 2.0.0 as compared to its previous version.

Answer (score 1):

The API is changed now. New packages, new classes.
 So it is really highly recommended to use **@Override** annotation for your map and reduce methods if you are planning to adopt the new API.  Otherwise, you are going to face some strange behaviours.

Here is an example of the [Old API](https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/tree/master/ch02/src/main/java/oldapi) and here is an example of the [New API](https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/tree/master/ch02/src/main/java).

Keep in mind that has nothing to do with the new YARN runtime.

Comment: Thanks a Lot but the example given is not for hadoop 2.0.0. Its the difference between previous two versions which is given in the link.

Comment: @user3180409 It is the new API (Hadoop 2) https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/tree/master/ch02/src/main/java

Comment: Chiron, you are explaining the difference between the mapred API and the mapreduce API (I think). Both are still available in Hadoop 2.0: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/package-summary.html

Comment: I believe OP is asking if Hadoop 2 changes mapreduce at all. In theory, it does not. It was more of an infrastructure/platform change.

Comment: @DonaldMiner The OP gives an illusion whether the source code of his MapReduce is going to be changed or not.

Comment: It shouldn't have to be changed. If anything, recompiled.